# Get data back to the original form from a second form

Tags: c#, forms, variables, public

I have two forms, and I create the second by using:

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.Show();
```

`Form2` has a variable that is public and changes every mousemove. I have a button on that form which, when press, saves the variable. Now the problem is that I don't know how to pass it back to `Form1`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use events.  `Form2` should define an event that is triggered as appropriate (it sounds like that should be when the button is clicked).  `Form1` can then subscribe to that event and do...whatever with it.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public event Action<string> MyEvent; //TODO give better name and set arguments for the Action

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string someValue = "Hello World!";  //TODO get value that you want to share

        if (MyEvent != null)
        {
            MyEvent(someValue);
        }
    }
}
```

And then in your main form:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 otherForm = new Form2();

    //subscribe to the event.  You could use a real method here, rather than an anonymous one, but I prefer doing it this way.
    otherForm.MyEvent += value =>
    {
        //do other stuff with "value".
        label1.Text = value;
    };

    otherForm.Show();
}
```

Comment: @KollingMaster Okay; what don't you get?  Telling me you don't get it doesn't really allow me to help you.  Did you try putting this code into a blank solution to see it work?  From there make small modifications, in particular try sending different data, or doing different things with the data on the main form.  From there consider actually moving the code to your actual application.

Comment: Thank you very much  got it now. The problem was i never worked with events before so i'll need to learn it now. Thanks